# Find all solutions to the equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt[3]{x}, x(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find all solutions to the equation $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt[3]{x}, x(0)=0$$

My solution for $x\neq 0$:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt[3]{x}$$
$$\frac{\frac{dx}{dt}}{\sqrt[3]{x}}dt=\int 1 dt$$
$$\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac 23} = t+C$$
$$x(0)=0 \Rightarrow C=0, \frac{3}{2}x^{\frac 23} = t$$
$$x^{\frac 23}=\frac 23 t$$
$$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac 8{27} t^3}$$

But I don't know what I can do with $x=0$.

Comment: I think that $x=0$ itself is a solution

Comment: And any point between them belongs to another solution of the given task.

Comment: Please check the exponents, you have some of them switched in the middle of the calculation.

Comment: @helpme so how can I write the final solution?

Answer (score 3):

The complete set of solutions is actually given by the family
$$x(t)=\left\{
\begin{align}
&0 & t <k \\
&\pm\sqrt{\frac{8}{27}(t-k)^3} & t\geq k
\end{align}
\right.
$$
with $k \in [0, +\infty]$.

It is immediate to verify that these are solutions. On the other hand if $x(t) \neq 0$ in a certain interval then by separation of variables (as you showed) we find that $x(t)$ has to be of the form
$$\pm \sqrt{\frac{8}{27}(t+C)^3}$$
on that interval. So there are no other solutions.

This Cauchy problem with no unique solution is an example of the *Peano phenomenon*, which is allowed by the fact that the Lipschitz condition for the equation fails.

Comment: Can you show how you get this arrangement of solutions?

Comment: Do we consider imaginary value as well? Because $(t+k)$ will be negative when $t <-k$

Comment: @Ri-Li Yes you are right, I got confused with other similar problems so I did not realize this simple fact. Now the answer should be ok, thanks a lot!

Comment: I had also missed a sign in the solution.

Comment: No worries. I was also confused whether in some parts they consider that