# Find all possible continuous solution of ODE $\frac{dx}{dt}=x^{1/3}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

Find all possible continuous solution of initial value problem(IVP) ODE $\frac{dx}{dt}=x^{1/3}$, $x(0)=0$.
Be sure to provide an argument that your list is complete and to consider both $t < 0$ and
$t > 0$.

I have directly solved it using separation of variable to get $x=\left(\frac 23\right)^{3/2}t^{3/2}.$ Now this only exists for $t>0$.

For $t<0$ I am not getting an answer. Moreover if $\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x)$ with $f(x(0))\neq 0$. I can use the uniqueness and existence(!!not uniqueness and existence of 1st order ODE) of $\int_{x(0)}^x\frac{dx}{f(x)}=F(x)=t$ and then find a solution as $F^{-1}(t)=x(t)$ over the region where $F$ is invertible. But here $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ which is $0$ at $t=0$ so I am stuck. Also I have to prove that my solution covers all possibilities. Please help.

Comment: Recently https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4527878/find-all-solutions-to-the-equation-fracdxdt-sqrt3x-x0-0, if you search, this is a frequent example, also with square root and other powers smaller than 1.

Comment: $x(t) \equiv 0$ is a solution.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I was searching for a similar example. Couldn't find it. Can you suggest me an effective way to search?

Comment: You can use approach0.xyz to search